# Free software for annotations (circles, arrows, etc.) in screen capture videos

Tags: video-editor, screen-casting, freeware

I have recorded some technical tutorial videos through screen capture. At certain points in these videos, I want to highlight buttons, text, etc. by circling them or putting arrows. An example effect can be seen here:

I know there are paid software out there -- Adobe Premiere Pro, Camtasia Studio, and the like. Is there any freeware that can help me achieve the same?

Related question: [Video tutorials: how to add labels, comments, arrows etc](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/5289/video-tutorials-how-to-add-labels-comments-arrows-etc)

Comment: Very, very closely related: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/good-open-source-video-editors

Answer (score 1):

There's CamStudio (GNU General Public License): http://camstudio.org/
It has screen and video annotations tools.